# How to write java code for dependency injection

Tags: java, static, dependencies

See two java codes of below,

```java
public class SecretDecoder {
    private AWSKMS client;

    public SecretDecoder(AWSKMS client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String Decode(String data, String keyId) {
        DecryptRequest request = new Request();
        ByteBuffer encodedBlob = getByteBuffer(data);

        request.withEncodedBlob(encodedBlob);
        request.withKeyId(keyId);
        DecryptResult result = client.decode(request);
        String decodedData = getString(result.getPlaintext());
        return decodedData;
    }
}
```

I don't think `DependentClient` is a dependency for this class. This class will be used to decode a secrete. The correct implementation should be like below,

```java
public class SecretDecoder {
    
    public static String Decode(String data, String keyId) {
        AWSKMS client = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().build();; 
        DecryptRequest request = new Request();
        ByteBuffer encodedBlob = getByteBuffer(data);

        request.withEncodedBlob(encodedBlob);
        request.withKeyId(keyId);
        DecryptResult result = client.decode(request);
        String decodedData = getString(result.getPlaintext());
        return decodedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you are trying to ask as your first code is using dependency injection already. Would be even much more scalable if "DependentClient" would be an interface

Comment: To add to @B001ᛦ comment...  Since you are passing in DependentClient via SecretDecoder's constructors, this is the beginnings of Dependency Injection.  However, a problem, is that SecretDecoder is dependent on two concrete classes (DependentClient and Request).  Depending on what may happen with the Request class in the future, it might be better to use a Factory to create that instance.  Also, there is nothing wrong with using a static method like you do in your second example, but it depends on the level of coupling your'e willing to accept in your application.

Comment: I updated the code to make it clear what it will do. It is helper class used to decrypt the secret saved in AWS KMS.
AWSKMS client is just a stateless client. I am not think this helper class will depend on it. It does not hold any data which will impact my helper class. I preferred second approach.